# Basic Django image runs locally but fail inside Kubernetes?

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes

I created a bare minimal Django project using

```
django-admin startproject
```

I then dockerized it using the following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFRED=1
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I built and pushed the image to ACR. I am able to run it locally using

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 <image_name>
```

and I am able access the site at localhost:8000.

However, when I try to deploy it inside a Kubernetes deployment with the following yml file, it just crashed and restart over and over.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demodjango-deployment
  labels:
    app: demodjango
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demodjango
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demodjango
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: demodjango
          image: djangonba.azurecr.io/demodjango:latest
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demodjango-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: demodjango
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
```

I am unable to access the page through the external IP address of the service demodjango-service either even at time where it somehow didn't crash.

I already made the following modification

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

I believe there is something fundamentally wrong with my approach? Can anyone tell me theoretically why it works on my machine but not inside a Kubernetes deployment (more particularly a pod I believe)?